# Run Selenium Application on different machine than where it was created

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, server, windows-server-2012-r2, web-testing

I have developed a Console App using VS2015 which uses Selenium WebDriver to test some websites.

I now want to install this app onto a server and run it there.
I have already installed the app on the server, but when I try to run it, I get an error saying that "Firefox binary couldn't be found in PATH or default". Firefox is installed in the default path C:\Program Files\Mozilla.

Have you got any suggestions on this? Do I need to install any part of Selenium on the server? (Selenium Standalone Server for example)
The server is running Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually caused by the environment variable %PATH%. The variable didn't contain the path for Firefox default installation, which is

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox
```

To fix the problem, I simply added that path to the environment variable %PATH% (you can find it by clicking Start, typing "environment variables", and clicking on "Environment Variables..." button on the bottom right of the System Properties tab that open when you look for "environment variables" in the Start menu.

That solved the issue.

Thank you Khaja for you answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's unable to find the Firefox binary on its own. So you have to specify the binary of Firefox explicitly. Use the below code to find the Firefox binary

> FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("path/to/binary"));
>   FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
>   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);

What I would recommend is for you to be using Firefox binary in your test suites and call the path of the executable from a properties file so that you don't have to compile all of your test cases again.